# Regex allow asterisk(*) only once time and in the end

Tags: regex, kleene-star

I want to pass only the strings like this:

```
abc*
123*
abc 123*
abc-123abc*
```

I don't want to pass strings like those:

```
 - abc**
 - abc*123
 - *abc
```

The asterisk must be in the end and only once time.

With the regex like `\*` I get all asterisk, but i dont klnow how i specified. I am not so good in regex.

Comment: Use `^[^*]*\*$`, see https://regex101.com/r/YHt6wa/1

Comment: then allow any kind of non asterix followed by one asterix `^[^*]+\*$` and limit it to the full string with ^....$

Comment: What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
^[^*]*\*$
```

Note it will also match a `*` string. If there must be at least two chars, replace the `[^*]*` part with `[^*]+` to match one or more chars other than `*` before the final `*`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YHt6wa/1). Details:

- `^`  - start of a string
- `[^*]*` - zero or more chars other than `*`, as many as possible (greedily)
- `\*` - a `*` char
- `$` - at the end of string.